# crr output list- remove df$ from coefficients?

Tags: r

I am using the cmprsk package to create a series of regressions. In the real models I used, I specified my models in the same way that is shown in the example that produces mel2 below. My problem is, I want the Melanoma$ in front of the coefficients to go away, as happens if I had specified the model like in mel1. Is there a way to delete that data frame prefix out of the object without re-running it?

```
library(cmprsk)
data(Melanoma, package = "MASS")

head(Melanoma)

mel1 <- crr(ftime = Melanoma$time, fstatus = Melanoma$status, cov1 = Melanoma[, c("sex", "age")], cencode = 2)

covs2 <- model.matrix(~ Melanoma$sex + Melanoma$age)[, -1]
mel2 <- crr(ftime = Melanoma$time, fstatus = Melanoma$status, cov1 = covs2, cencode = 2)
```

What I want:
[image]

What I have:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `data` argument in `model.matrix`, and wrap the `crr` call in `with(Melanoma, ...)`

```r
covs2 <- model.matrix(~ sex + age, data = Melanoma)[, -1]
mel2 <- with(Melanoma, crr(ftime = time, fstatus = status, 
                           cov1 = covs2, cencode = 2))

mel2$coef
#>        sex        age 
#> 0.58838573 0.01259388
```

If you are stuck with existing models like this:

```r
covs2 <- model.matrix(~ Melanoma$sex + Melanoma$age)[, -1]
mel2 <- crr(ftime = Melanoma$time, fstatus = Melanoma$status,
            cov1 = covs2, cencode = 2)
```

You could simply rename the coefficients like this

```r
names(mel2$coef) <- c("sex", "age")

mel2
#> convergence:  TRUE 
#> coefficients:
#>     sex     age 
#> 0.58840 0.01259 
#> standard errors:
#> [1] 0.271800 0.009301
#> two-sided p-values:
#>  sex  age 
#> 0.03 0.18
```

Comment: yeah, but I want to try to get rid of the Melanoma$ without re-running the regressions. Is that possible?

Comment: hey, I'm trying to figure out a way to make this easier for bigger regression results with a lot more variables that may differ slightly. I gave this a shot but it does nothing, any chance I can get a bit more feedback from you here: names(mel2$coef) <- gsub(x = names(mel2$coef), pattern = "\\Melanoma$", replacement = "")

Comment: @tchoup sure - try `names(mel2$coef) <- gsub("Melanoma\\$", "", names(mel2$coef))`